# UTF-8 malforphmed byte sequence error

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, byte, validationerror

When I tried to validate a recent project, I got multiple errors which say "Malformed byte sequence: 92." What does this mean? It's got something to do with the charset UTF-8, but I can't find ANY information online about what this problem is or how to fix it. If anyone out there could give me a hand, that would be great!!! I only know HTML, CSS and a little JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 encoding in my project. I'm building a website.

Comment: One of your documents is not UTF-8, but your toolchain expects it to be. Make sure you’re saving as UTF-8, and not something else like CP1252 (often called ANSI).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out. I was saving my projects as ANSI. There was a setting under the "File" tab in my code editor (Programmer's Notepad) entitled "Encoding". I changed that to UTF-8 and it cleared up the validation problems.

Comment: If your page contains data from a database make sure the database structure is the same as the page collecting the data. E.g. UTF-8 page -> UTF-8 database table encoding. Also make sure that if you import data from an other encode database or if you copy and paste text in your database GUI you might get the Malformed byte sequence error if for instance the text contains characters that are not UTF-8 encoded (so 'ë' should be 'Ã«' in a UTF-8 encoded table).